# How to parse specific values from a CSS URL

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, parsing, url

I'm trying to parse some specific hex color values from a css URL (not all the contents), but don't know how to figure that out using Python.

The URL looks like the below:

https://abcdomain.com/styles/theme.css

And its contents are :

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

.bg-primary {
  background-color: #2ccfff;
  color: white;
}

.bg-success {
  background-color: #8b88ff;
  color: white;
}

.bg-info {
  background-color: #66ccff;
  color: white;
}

.bg-warning {
  background-color: #ff9900;
  color: white;
}

.bg-danger {
  background-color: #7bb31a;
  color: white;
}

.bg-orange {
  background-color: #f98e33;
  color: white;
}
```

I just need to parse the "background-color" hex values for specific entries, starting from "warning" until "orange" ONLY.

I tries `urllib.request` but didn't work accurately with me.

I will be so grateful if anyone could help me get this values using a Python script.

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: What you meant by *urllib.request don't work accurately...*? Requesting to URL returns the expected content? I mean CSS content.

Answer (score 2):

I added an extra 'f' to your CSS code, because it didn't validate.

You can download a file using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master) and parse CSS using [cssutils](http://cthedot.de/cssutils). The following code finds all `background-color` instances and puts them in a dict with the CSS selector.

```
import requests
import cssutils

# Use this instead of requests if you want to read from a local file
# css = open('test.css').read()

url = 'https://abcdomain.com/styles/theme.css'
r = requests.get(url)
css = r.content

sheet = cssutils.parseString(css)

results = {}
for rule in sheet:
    if rule.type == rule.STYLE_RULE:
        for prop in rule.style:
            if prop.name == 'background-color':
                results[rule.selectorText] = prop.value

print(results)
```

This prints the following result:

```
{
  '.bg-primary': '#2ccfff',
  '.bg-success': '#8b88ff',
  '.bg-info': '#6cf',
  '.bg-warning': '#f90',
  '.bg-danger': '#7bb31a',
  '.bg-orange': '#f98e33'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zan for the script, appreciated. But what if I need to get specific range of values from that CSS list. for example the hex codes from "bg-warning" to "bg-orange" ONLY.

Comment: `results` is a dictionary, you can use standard dictionary lookup to get the values you need: `bg-colour = results['.bg-orange']`